# Change bootstrap NavBar Colour 2.1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Struggling to find where this is done as see the new default colour is now white. Where would I change the colour in Twitter Bootstrap for the NavBar?

Comment: Change the color to what? The old black color or a new color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the new default is white, or more accurately light. You can use the navbar-inverse class in your outer div.

That outer div should now look like:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
```

instead of

```
<div class="navbar">
```

Comment: I just love SO. My every problem has an answer here. +1.

Comment: You've got to love Bootstrap!

Answer (score 0):

Still slightly different.

Now (v2.3.2) http://jsfiddle.net/MXYjX/8/

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #1B1B1B;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #222222, #111111);
}
```

Was (v2.0.4) (with firefox) http://jsfiddle.net/MXYjX/7/ And there was a box-shadow

```
.navbar-inner {
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #222222);
 }
```